# Autokey - Focus App Window If Running, Launch App If Not

Tags: bash, process-management, python3, pgrep, autokey

I'm trying to obtain the processID of `pcmanfm` like this:

```
pgrep -f "pcmanfm"
```

When `pcmanfm` is not running, the command above returns nothing (as I expect).

However, when I run the command from python, it returns a process ID even when `pcmanfm` is not running:

```
processID = os.system('pgrep -f "pcmanfm"')
```

Furthermore, if you run the command above multiple times at a python3 prompt, it returns a different processID each time. All the while, `pcmanfm` has been closed prior to these commands.

```
>>> processID = os.system('pgrep -f "pcmanfm"')
17412
>>> processID = os.system('pgrep -f "pcmanfm"')
17414
>>> processID = os.system('pgrep -f "pcmanfm"')
17416
```

This is really messing up my ability to launch `pcmanfm` if it isn't currently running. My script thinks it is running when it isn't.

Why is this happening?

I'm actually encountering this issue in an [Autokey](https://autokey.github.io/index.html) script that I've attempted to write based on this [video](https://youtu.be/AK2UKUfsV3g?t=580) I watched. Here's my current script:

```
processID = system.exec_command('pgrep -f "pcmanfm" | head -1',True)
dialog.info_dialog("info",processID)

if (processID):
    cmd = "wmctrl -lp | grep " + processID + " | awk '{print $1}'"
    windowID = system.exec_command(cmd,True)
    # dialog.info_dialog("info",windowID)
    cmd = "wmctrl -iR " + windowID
    #dialog.info_dialog("info",cmd)
    system.exec_command(cmd,False)
else:
    #os.system("pcmanfm /home/user/Downloads")
    cmd = "/usr/bin/pcmanfm /home/user/Downloads"
    system.exec_command(cmd,False)
```

The problem is, I keep getting processIDs even when `pcmanfm` isn't running. The script properly focuses `pcmanfm` if it is running, but it won't launch it if it isn't.

**Update:** I finally got this script to work by taking out `-f` and replacing it with `-nx` (from @they 's advice). Also, I added some exception handling to ignore autokey exceptions caused by empty output that's expected. Additionally, I converted it to a (more flexible) function so that it will service a wider variety of commands/applications:

```
import re
def focusOrLaunch(launchCommand):
    appName = re.findall('[^\s/]+(?=\s|$)',launchCommand)[0]
    processID = None
    try:
        processID = system.exec_command('pgrep -nx "' + appName + '"',True)
    except Exception as e:
        #dialog.info_dialog("ERROR",str(e))
        pass

    #dialog.info_dialog("info",processID)
    if (processID):
        cmd = "wmctrl -lp | grep " + processID + " | awk '{print $1}'"
        windowID = system.exec_command(cmd,True)
        # dialog.info_dialog("info",windowID)
        cmd = "wmctrl -iR " + windowID
        #dialog.info_dialog("info",cmd)
        system.exec_command(cmd,False)
    else:
        system.exec_command(launchCommand,False)
    
cmd = "/usr/bin/pcmanfm ~/Downloads"
focusOrLaunch(cmd)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Proposed solution:**

Remove the `-f` option from your `pgrep` command.

---

**Explanation:**

You probably get the process ID of the shell that is executed to run your command. A new shell process with a new PID will be created for every `system.exec_command`.

Run e.g. `sh -c 'pgrep -af nonexistent'` and check the output. You will probably get something like

```
11300 sh -c pgrep -af nonexistent
```

With an existing command I also get a line for the shell

```
sh -c 'pgrep -af sshd'
695 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
11207 sshd: pi [priv]
11224 sshd: pi@pts/0
11331 sshd: [accepted]
11343 sh -c pgrep -af sshd
```

Depending on the PID values, your `head` command might extract the PID of a process you are looking for or the PID of the shell process.

With option `-f` you explicitly tell `pgrep` to search the whole command line instead of the process name only. This way it will find the string in the shell's command line argument.

Without `-f` you won't get the shell process.

```
$ sh -c 'pgrep -a sshd'
695 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
11207 sshd: pi [priv]
11224 sshd: pi@pts/0
11364 sshd: [accepted]
```

Comment: ... which means dropping the `-f` option would solve the issue.

Comment: Hmm, without the `-f`, autokey [errors](https://i.imgur.com/aseXSlj.png) out on this line alone `processID = system.exec_command('pgrep "pcmanfm" | head -1',True)`

Comment: So, it turns out that `system.exec_command` throws an exception when the command's output is an empty line. @they Thank you for your comment. @Bodo Thanks for the elaboration. I've updated my question to provide the script that ultimately worked in Autokey.

Comment: @LonnieBest You should not use `pgrep` with `head` in a pipeline. Instead, use `pgrep` with `-o` or `-n` to get the single PID corresponding to the oldest or most recently started process that matches the expression. Also consider using `-x` so that you don't accidentally match process names that contains your expression as a sub-string.

Comment: @they Wise suggestions. Thank you. I updated my question to reflect your advice in the final script.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on focusing a program's window if it's running or launching the program if it's not. I used **Firefox** in the example, but I'm hoping it would work the same way for your **pcmanfm** if you made the appropriate edits to remove **Firefox** from the example code and replace it with the equivalent **PCManFM** information.

*Note that I used the **subprocess.Popen** function because it allows you to execute other code and/or interact with the process with the **subprocess.communicate** function while the process is running. If that isn't needed, you can use the **subprocess.run** function instead.*

```
output = system.exec_command("wmctrl -l", getOutput=True)
if "Firefox" in output:
    window.activate("Firefox",switchDesktop=True)
else:
    subprocess.Popen(["firefox"])
```

Comment: The issue with `pcmanfm` is that it doesn't indicate its application name on the title bar of its window. Instead, it only shows the folder name of where it currently is in the file system. Therefore, `pcmanfm` cannot be found in the output of `wmctrl -l`. This is why I have endured the trouble of finding the processID of each open window. With it, I can discover the command that launched each window and search for `pcmanfm` in those commands.

Your solution will work for most applications, but for applications like `pcmanfm` (which doesn't showcase its name on the title bar), you need more.

Comment: What do you get in the third column of the output of the wmctrl -lx command while PCManFM is running? If I do that command while Firefox is running, I get Navigator.Firefox in that column. If you get some useful (i.e.: unique) output in that column, this can be done by window class instead of by using the title bar.

Comment: As I mentioned, it only shows the [folder name of where I'm at in pcmanfm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl76m.png), which changes upon navigation to other folders. Window class may be a reliable alternative, but the final code shown at the bottom of my question, is working perfectly for every application I've tried so far (including pcmanfm).

Comment: The problem is that, in Wayland, windows are managed by the programs that want them and not by the X server and compositor. As a result, the only actual "awareness" of them is by the programs that initiate them.

You might be able to trick the system, though, at least as far as wmctrl is concerned. What happens if you do ```pcmanfm --class=foo``` and then run the ```wmctrl -lx``` command? Does it see the foo class? If so, there's some existing AutoKey syntax that works with classes.